# Define mapping setup in XML file for use during runtime

Tags: c#, xml, orm

Before I go about reinventing the wheel I'd like to find out if there is some existing method to define object-to-object mappings in XML to be able to change my object-to-object mappings without re-compiling the application.

Something like:

```
<Mappings>
  <Mapping>
    <SourceObject>PersonDto</SourceObject>
    <DestinationObject>Person</DestinationObject>
    <map src="FirstName" dest="FirstName"></map>
    <map src="LastName" dest="LastName"></map>
    <map src="IsAlive" dest="1"></map>
  <Mapping>
</Mappings>
```

I've been using AutoMapper, but it doesn't seem to have this support.  Obviously I could roll my own but...

Comment: If you are willing to serialize your objects, XmlSerializer has the [XmlAttributeOverrides Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which may allow you to "override the default way of serializing a set of objects" specifically to "control how each field, property, or **class** is serialized."